# PHP if conditional statement for SQL count

Tags: php, mysqli

I am working on a form, in which it is required that I check if there are 1 or more instances of a particular value/ values. The problem is that on testing, I get "Dates are already booked", even though the values I select are not.

This is my code -

```
if ($_POST) {
   if (isset($_POST['proceedtopaypal'])){
    $apartment = $_POST['apartment'];
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    $surname = $_POST['surname'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $mobile = $_POST['mobile'];
    $pax = $_POST['pax'];
    $address = $_POST['address'];
    $remarks = $_POST['remarks'];
    $day_from = $_POST['day_from'];
    $month_from = $_POST['month_from'];
    $year_from = $_POST['year_from'];
    $booking_from = $year_from."-".$month_from."-".$day_from; (format- yyyy-mm-dd)
    $day_to = $_POST['day_to'];
    $month_to = $_POST['month_to'];
    $year_to = $_POST['year_to'];
    $booking_to = $year_to."-".$month_to."-".$day_to;
    $no_of_nights = abs(strtotime($booking_to) - strtotime($booking_from));     
    $days = floor($no_of_nights / (60*60*24));
    $validdate = false;
    $buttonpressed = false;

            function IsInjected($str)
    {
      $injections = array('(\n+)',
                  '(\r+)',
                  '(\t+)',
                  '(%0A+)',
                  '(%0D+)',
                  '(%08+)',
                  '(%09+)'
                  );
      $inject = join('|', $injections);
      $inject = "/$inject/i";
      if(preg_match($inject,$str))
        {
        return true;
      }
      else
        {
        return false;
      }
    }

if (!checkdate($month_from, $day_from, $year_from)) {
        echo "Check in date is invalid";
    }
    else if (!checkdate($month_to, $day_to, $year_to)) {
        echo "Check out date is invalid";
    }
    else if ($booking_from > $booking_to) {
             echo "Check in date is after check out date";
    }
    // check if all info is filled in 
    else if (($name == "Name") || ($surname == "surname") || ($email == "Email") || ($mobile == "mobile") || ($address == "Address")) {
        echo "Please fill in the missing information";
    }
    else if (IsInjected($email)) {
        echo "Not an email";
    } 
    else if ($validdate == false) {
        $final = true;
        include 'connect.php';
        $sql = "SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM room_nights WHERE apartmentID= '$apartment' AND dates >= '$booking_from' AND dates < '$booking_to'";
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
        $data = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
        echo $row[0];   

        if ($data > 0) {
            echo "Dates are already booked!";
        }
        else {
            echo "Proceed";
        }

        }

    }
}
```

What would be the best solution for this problem so that I can proceed with my works.

Comment: Final small question - if I want to save the new range of dates selected in the database, how do I go about doing that. As in if the form can be processed, I want to save the new selectedd dates in a table. For example if the dates chosen are 2015-08-10 - 2015-08-12,  I save 2015-08-10, 2015-08-11, and 2015-08-12.

Comment: why you wana insert three dates?

Comment: Becasue I would need them stored as reference for the future, in order to be able to check for dates availablle.

Comment: yes you can save dates like that if you have one col `dates` in database and i think it will b better if you open new question with relevant code, will be easy to answer according to your code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$data = mysqli_num_rows($result);` is useless. When you use `SELECT COUNT(*)` in your query, you should not use `mysqli_num_rows` function. You can use just this:

```
$sql = "SELECT COUNT(*)  FROM room_nights WHERE apartmentID= '$apartment' AND dates >= '$booking_from' AND dates < '$booking_to'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
    $row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
    echo $row[0];   

    if ($row[0] > 0) {
        echo "Dates are already booked!";
    }
    else {
        echo "Proceed";
    }
```